# How to configure a connection to GitHub using v2 from Cloudformation Pipeline YAML template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

They're many documents and know hows about making a connection to GitHub using v1 from a Cloudformation Pipeline, but since the GitHub change to v2 I can't find anything.

In the past, the definition was:

```
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      RoleArn: !GetAtt DeploymentRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Source
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Version: 1
                Provider: GitHub
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: Source
          Configuration:
            Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
            Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
            Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
            OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubPersonalAccessToken
            PollForSourceChanges: false
          RunOrder: 1
```

and you did need to generate an Access Token on GitHub, save it and use it as a variable. It worked fine in the distant past, but now I don't find anything to make it work with v2 and the code above fails with `CREATE_FAILED "Encountered unsupported property Configuration" - ""ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [Pipeline]."`

Answer (score 1):

You have to **fix your indentation**. `Configuration` should be under `Actions`:

```
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineBucket
        Type: S3
      RoleArn: !GetAtt DeploymentRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: Source
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Version: 1
                Provider: GitHub
              OutputArtifacts:
                 - Name: Source
              Configuration:
                 Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
                 Repo: !Ref GitHubRepo
                 Branch: !Ref GitHubBranch
                 OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubPersonalAccessToken
                 PollForSourceChanges: false
              RunOrder: 1
```

Comment: Many thanks! Actually, I did have to fix identation in the whole Pipeline based on your suggestion. It worked.